# YouTube black screen when changing settings

Tags: youtube

I like to watch YouTube videos in full HD (1080p). When I open a video, it starts on auto; when I click another setting the screen goes black. I am able to view stills by running the mouse on the timeline but nothing else. I then have to refresh to watch it.

If I watch the same video within a Facebook post, I can switch the view settings without problems.

I’m using Google Chrome and it’s up to date, Adobe and Java up to date and cookies cleared. And I still have this error.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I fixed it. Went into my plug-ins (chrome://plugins) I disable adobe flash, downloaded adobe flash from website, and then re-enabled. Then, press start on your desktop and open up the program run. Type in "regedit" click on "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE>SOFTWARE>Policies>Google>Update" then double click on "UpdateDefault" and then change the "0" to a "1". Then go to your settings bar on the top right of google chrome, about google chrome, and make sure you're up to date. I honestly don't know why this worked, but it did. I hope it helps man!